# Change in content of build_file in new_git_repository causes cloning again

Tags: git, bazel

There is an external dependency declared in WORKSPACE as below:

```py
new_git_repository(
    name = "someproj",
    build_file = "//:external-deps/someproj/BUILD.someproj",
    commit = "{commit hash}",
    remote = "https://somewhere.com/someproj.git",
    shallow_since = "111111111 -0600",
)
```

in `BUILD.someproj` when I change some targets (i.e. change name, deps, etc.) and run `bazel build something/depending/on/someproj:depender` bazel tries to clone from `https://somewhere.com/someproj.git` again! However, nothing in the repo is changed.
Shouldn't it cache the cloned repo? Since it's not changed, but the BUILD file working on it.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the `BUILD.someproj` file is part of the checksum for Bazel to know when to re-run the `new_git_repository` repository rule, along with other attributes like `remote` and `commit`. The invalidation algorithm has nothing to do with git, because it applies across all kinds of repository rules, and across all attributes.

This may be improved with an integration between `git_repository` and Bazel's repository cache. The feature request is being tracked in [this issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/5116).